# Dynamically adding @font-face to a svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

my situation is as follows:

The website should include several svgs provided by my client. Those svgs include texts that should be rendered in a custom font. My client's authoring tool however does not include the font in the svg during the export process.

I tried to solve this as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var svgs = document.getElementsByClassName('load-fonts');

    if (svgs.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for(var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
                var svg   = svgs[i];
                var defs  = document.createElement('defs');
                var sheet = document.createElement('style');
                sheet.type = "text/css";
                sheet.innerHTML = ""
                    + "@font-face {font-family: 'GloberRegular';"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.eot') "
                    + "url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}"
                    + "@font-face {font-family: 'GloberBook';"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.eot') "
                    + "url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}"
                    + "@font-face {font-family: 'GloberBold';"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_bold-webfont.eot') "
                    + "url('/dist/fonts/glober_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');"
                    + "src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_bold-webfont.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}"
                    + "@media screen and (min-resolution:0dppx) {@font-face {font-family: 'GloberRegular';src: url('/dist/fonts/glober_regular-webfont.svg') format('svg')};";
                defs.appendChild(sheet);
                svg.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(defs);

                $(sheet).clone().appendTo( svg.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0] );
            }
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

This approach works in Safari but apparently in no other browser. I cannot find a fix that loads the font.

Another option would be to batch process those svg files (using e.g. gulp) and add the font face annotation there, but I could not find a suitable toolchain and plugins for the job.

Any help would be very appreciated !

Best regards,

Jan

Comment: oh my word - never use `.innerHTML = ` for pure text, use `.textContent =`, so that whatever malicious code *might* be in there, doesn't trigger. Also why in the world would you do this, why are you not just using a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfile.css">`? SVG is part of HTML since HTML5 so you can just load them *directly* as markup in the HTML and the styles defined in your CSS will kick in for them (provided your selectors match the SVG elements you need to style of course).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it does not however resolve the problem.

Comment: it most certainly should - if *your code* just includes the `<link rel="....">` stylesheet import for the font, then the text inside the SVG should work fine: http://jsbin.com/yamekegabi/edit?html,js,output -- And If *that* doesn't work, then you have a different question from this one really (namely: why do my fonts not style text in SVG)

Comment: @Jan Did u solve this? I have similar problem and looking for a solution. I read somewhere that inlining fonts may work.

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements can't be created with createElement (that's only for HTML).

```
var defs  = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
var sheet = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'style');
```

I don't think IE supports innerHTML so you may need to change that to textContent to get things to work there.

Comment: While that is valuable information, it did not resolve the problem. Font still appears in Safari and does not render in Chrome / FF.

Comment: Can you create something runnable then e.g. a jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hfr1tb38/ It seems to be not runnable though as it references remote files (for the svg & fonts)

Comment: You don't seem to have applied the information in my answer to your jsfiddle. On top of that you can't do cross-domain manipulation of data so the whole thing fails because the data i.e. https://assag.jangrgeor.me/dist/img/machines/bass2020_de.svg is not on the same domain as https://jsfiddle.net